# How to tell Sublime(Linter) to use ZSH instead of BASH?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sublimetext3, zsh

I'm using zsh but SublimeLinter is taking its path from the bash shell, resulting in unfound executables. I have for example eslint installed using npm globally, and it needs to find that in the NVM directory which is set in .zprofile. This is the debug output of Sublime:

```
SublimeLinter: user shell: /bin/bash 
SublimeLinter: computed PATH using /bin/bash:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I've set the default shell in my system to zsh using `chsh -s /bin/zsh` so I have no idea why it's using bash and I can't find info about this.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on OSX.

Comment: "I have no idea why it's using bash." Well, not every program consults `$SHELL` or `/etc/passwd` before spinning up a shell, especially when it's a GUI program where `$SHELL` is not set (oh, and on OS X your user is not even listed in `/etc/passwd`, so it just can't find out your shell from there; I have no knowledge about `opendirectoryd` so I won't comment on that).

Comment: Most programs don't look in /etc/passwd at all; they call the `getpw*` library functions.  Which you can quickly do yourself from the command line with something like `perl -le 'print join ":", getpwnam("username")'`.

Comment: 0x80 did you ever figure this out? I'm running into exactly the same problem. ST3, using zsh, but I see in sublimelinter's debug log that is' using `/bin/bash` as the user shell. So it can't find the linters I've installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's using Bash instead of ZSH. It probably isn't the problem but I would ensure you do not have bash files such as a `.bash_profile` in your home folder even though you're using ZSH. Also, I'd try to make sure you open ST via ZSH (again, probably doesn't make a difference).

If it's still not working, you could always manually specify the path to the linter via SublimeLinter's user settings JSON file:

```
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [
            "/path-to-linter"
        ],
        "windows": []
    }
```